# Re : XML API - GXL1PRS

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, cobol

I am trying to implement XML API calling z/OS XML System services Parser process in our environment. For this, I took the example XMLPRS1 program included in redbook http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247810.pdf(Page Number 187) In execution, after the XMLSS-GXL1PRS call is returning the following error: **Length Input Buffer: 256 GXL1PRS Return Code: 12 reason Code: 2387 Error offset in doc: 0.**

Kindly share your views to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste a minimum amount of data that produces the problem? Did you make any changes to the sample program (it is large, did you check for pastos)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. No we have not made any changes to the source code, we just used the program XMLPRS1 present in the page number 187 of above mentioned pdf.

Comment: Need that sample data. Need you to confirm that there are no pastos. On each "page" of the PDF, check the top and bottom lies appear in your program. Count the lines and confirm to your program.

Answer (score 1):

An error at offset 0 in the document is most likely to be an xml declaration, e.g.  "< ? xml version='1.0' encoding='uff-8' ? >" that does not start exactly at the 0th byte of the document.

See if someone text-editored your data and inserted an additional 4-byte byte order mark, things like windows notepad and the visual studio editor are always doing this, but I've seen it with other text editors.  Or even if you just have a space before your xml declaration, you have an invalid document.

You can remove the xml declaration, it is optional, and then any amount of xml whitespace (TAB, LF, CR, SPACE) is valid before the root element tag.  Or you can remove the prepended bytes.